# error on checkboxes in validate plugin jquery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I want to move the error that I get if no checkboxes are checked to after the last checkbox's text.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myform" value="aaa">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value='' />x
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value='' />y
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value='something' />z
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            'test[]': {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
if (element.is(':checkbox')) {
    $(element).parent().last().addClass('error');
} else {
    error.insertAfter(element);
}
```

But this add's class to the parent of the checkboxes and I want the class to be added after the last text after the checkbox which in this case is "z". Also when I use this code of mine, the error doesn't show only class is added to the parent.

**[JSFiddle Demo with parent class being added](http://jsfiddle.net/aJBK9/5/)**

**[JSFiddle Demo with error showing](http://jsfiddle.net/aJBK9/6/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').validate({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.is('[name="test[]"]')) {
                error.appendTo(element.parent());
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        rules: {
            'test[]': {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.error {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form id="myform" value="aaa">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value='' />x
        <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value='' />y
        <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value='something' />z</div>
    <input name="test" required />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```